# Magento getReadConnection() Error in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 134

Tags: magento

There is an error suddenly started popping up. The error occurs on various part of website like cart area, product detail page etc..

I am running my site on local server.
the error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getReadConnection() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 134

I have googled the issue but that didn't helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the class and the resource model. Please check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4295/getreadconnection-error). I hope solve your problem.